# writeFile() method doesn't write all lines to text file [JAVA]

Tags: java, arraylist, writefile

I am trying to write the contents of an arraylist to a text file. I am partially able to do this with my newbie coding skills, however at the moment it only writes the first line out of 48 lines to the text file.

I would assume that this might be due to the fact that i do not have a loop anywhere in my code however, i am not entirely sure whether id need a while loop, or for loop and where exactly i would need to put it? Could this perhaps be also due to my `readFile` method using `String(readAllBytes(get(filename)))` as opposed to reading in line by line?

```
    public static void main(String... p) throws IOException {

        List<SensorInfo> readings = new ArrayList<>();

        String filedata = readFile("client-temp.txt");

        SensorInfo info = new SensorInfo(filedata);
        readings.add(info);

        String data = createStringFromInfo(readings);
        System.out.println("Lines: " + readings.size());
        writeFile("datastore.txt", data);
    }
}
```

**writeFile**

```
public static void writeFile(String filename, String content)
    {
        try
        {
            Files.write(get(filename), content.getBytes());
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error wiring file: " + e);
        }
    }
```

**createStringFromInfo**

```
public static String createStringFromInfo(List<SensorInfo> infoList)
    {
        String data = "";
        for (SensorInfo info : infoList)
        {
            data += info.asData();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

**SensorInfo**
http://pastebin.com/9DDDGzwV

Comment: What `writeFile` method?

Comment: writeFile("datastore", data);

Comment: `createStringFromInfo`?

Comment: please find my edits above @MadProgrammer

Comment: There is only one `SensorInfo` object in your `readings` `List`, so unless that one object contains all the lines you're expecting, I don't really see how it can write more ...

Comment: Might be useful to see the `SensorInfo` constructor which accepts a String as an argument.

Comment: @MadProgrammer i understand what you are saying. Is there a way i can store all the lines in that one object?

Comment: @adamdc78 please find link to SensorInfo in my edits

Comment: You're splitting your entire input on `,` in the `SensorInfo(String data)` Constructor but only using the first four strings in the resulting array and discarding the rest in your  `SensorInfo(String... parms)` Constructor.  You could add a method which splits your input and then uses a for loop to instantiate a `SensorInfo` for each grouping of 4 Strings in the split (you'll need validation here and to increase your counter by 4 for each iteration).  You would want to add this OUTSIDE of your `SensorInfo` class.

Comment: Yes, but you'd need to change it so that it could not only store those lines, but could also provide some kind of access to them...

Comment: @adamdc78 just to reiterate what you've said, create a method which splits the input (which in this case would be "client-temp.txt") and then use a for loop that will create an instance of SensorInfo for each grouping of 4 strings?

Comment: @MadProgrammer what do you mean by access?

Comment: @rr0102 Correct.  Constructors are for a single instance of your class, but you've got data to instantiate 12 SensorInfo in this case (48 lines).  Your `String...` constructor is also NOT safe as you can pass in 0 or more Strings but it doesn't check that the number of Strings passed is at least 4, so you will likely get `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exceptions with corrupt or partial data.

Comment: @rr0102 The `SensorInfo` would (presumably) contain a `List` of the rows of data, you need to provide interested parties some way to gain access to it (like getter of some kind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MadProgrammer is right.
If I got it right, the file `client-temp.txt` has multiple lines; each one representing data from a single `SensorInfo` object. When you read all of them into `filedata` and pass it as a parameter for the constructor of `SensorInfo`, only the first line will be used to instantiate a single `SensorInfo` object, as you can clearly see from the source in the link you posted. All the remaining lines will be discarded. Keep in mind that a constructor of a class will always instantiate a single object of that class.
To resolve the issue you should read line by line from the file `client-temp.txt` and pass each one as a parameter for the creation of a new `SensorInfo` object that will be added to the list.

Here is a suggestion for your new main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<SensorInfo> readings = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("client-temp.txt"))) {
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            readings.add(new SensorInfo(line));
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to read data file");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String data = createStringFromInfo(readings);
    System.out.println("Lines: " + readings.size());
    writeFile("datastore.txt", data);
}
```

Regards

Comment: in terms of reading the file, would you recommended that i change from using readAllBytes to BufferedReader where i can then read line by line?

Comment: Just added some reference code. I am assuming you are using at least java 1.7 otherwise the try-with-resources construction wont work. Let me know...